# PHP - Pass in $filter and $update arrays as variables in the `MongoDB\Collection::updateMany` method

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to pass in my `$filter` and `$update` arrays as variables using the [PHP MongoDB updateMany method](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-updateMany/).

The official documentation provides the following template for `updateMany`:

```
function updateMany($filter, $update, array $options = []): MongoDB\UpdateResult
```

with `$filter` as an `array|object` and `$update` as an `array|object`.

I am able to successfully use `updateMany` when I hard-code the `$filter` and `$update` arrays like so:

**Option 1: Hard-code in the arrays (SUCCESS)**

```
$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB");
$db = new MongoDB\Database($mongo, "myDB");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("articles");
$result = $collection->updateMany(
    ["_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("5cae4176af659c1ba03591b5")],
    ['$set' => ["title" => "update_test"]]
);
```

However, it does not work when I create array variables and try to pass those in instead:

**Option 2: Pass in array variables (ERROR)**

```
$filter_string = "[\"_id\" => new \\MongoDB\\BSON\\ObjectID(\"5cae4171af659c1ba03591b3\")]";
$update_string = "['\$set' => [\"title\" => \"update_test\"]]";

$filter = explode(',', $filter_string);
$update = explode(',', $update_string);

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB");
$db = new MongoDB\Database($mongo, "myDB");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("articles");
$result = $collection->updateMany(
    [$filter], // Does not work as $filter(without the brackets) either.
    [$update] // Does not work as $update (without the brackets) either.
);
```

**Option 2 Error Message**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: First key in $update argument is not an update operator in /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/UpdateMany.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(1005): MongoDB\Operation\UpdateMany->__construct('myDB', 'articles', Array, Array, Array) #1 /var/www/html/mySite/update.php(105): MongoDB\Collection->updateMany(Array, Array) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/UpdateMany.php on line 82
```

That didn't work. So then I thought maybe PHP would automatically interpret the `[]` in a string as array delimiters if I passed the entirety of the arrays as strings instead (of course that doesn't work):

**Option 3: Pass in array variables as strings (ERROR)**

```
$filter_string = "[\"_id\" => new \\MongoDB\\BSON\\ObjectID(\"5cae4171af659c1ba03591b3\")]";
$update_string = "['\$set' => [\"title\" => \"update_test\"]]";

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB");
$db = new MongoDB\Database($mongo, "myDB");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("articles");
$result = $collection->updateMany(
    $filter_string,
    $update_string
);
```

**Option 3 Error Message**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected $update to have type "array or object" but found "string" in /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/UpdateMany.php(78): MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException::invalidType('$update', '['$set' => ["ti...', 'array or object') #1 /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(1005): MongoDB\Operation\UpdateMany->__construct('myDB', 'articles', '["_id" => new \\...', '['$set' => ["ti...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/mySite/update.php(105): MongoDB\Collection->updateMany('["_id" => new \\...', '['$set' => ["ti...') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php on line 32
```

Tl;dr: In what format do I pass in the `$filter` and `$update` variables in the PHP `updateMany` method?

Comment: What is the point in `explode` by comma? And what do you expect by creating strings with filter/update values?

Comment: In my source code, the original `$filter` and `$update` data comes in as strings through PHP `$_GET` methods which I then `explode` by comma into arrays

Comment: You don't get what you need by exploding. Output values and see what you have.

Comment: The exploding is irrelevant for the current example, but is in place in case there are multiple comma-delimited filters (`$filter`) or update (`$update`) criteria in the URI

Comment: You still don't understand that __string__ (exploded or not) is not __the same__ as array.

Comment: Oh dear, I have made a grave mistake. I thought the `field => value` format was a proprietary MongoDB format so I was incorrectly trying to adapt the format to work with PHP by turning all the `field => value`'s into strings...I need to `explode` by `field` and `value` (i.e. separate `title` and `update_test`, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could directly achieve like this,

```
$filterOption = ["_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("5cae4176af659c1ba03591b5")],
$updateOption = ["title" => "update_test"];
```

And in your update query

```
$result = $collection->updateMany(
    $filterOption, 
    ['$set' => $updateOption], 
);
```

This should work.

Comment: No, sorry, I get the same error as in my **Option 2 Error**: `Uncaught MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: First key in $update argument is not an update operator in /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/UpdateMany.php:82 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mySite/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(1005): MongoDB\Operation\UpdateMany->__construct('myDB', 'articles', Array, Array, Array) ` Also, my testing proves that the `['$set' =>["" => ""]]` format is necessary

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you check once? I missed `$set` part in query

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I shouldn't have tried to incorporate the `['$set' => ]` part into my `$update` variable. I now have a lot of fixing-up to do with my formatting due to my misunderstanding of how arrays in PHP work...